# Compiled Apache – no conf-enabled/conf-available/mods-available etc. folders

Tags: apache2

I just compiled apache (httpd-2.4.23) using these commands:

```
APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2
APACHE_ENVVARS=$APACHE_CONFDIR/envvars
CFLAGS="-O2 -DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE"

./configure --prefix=$APACHE_CONFDIR
make
make install
```

However, there are folders conf-enabled/conf-available/mods-available etc. missing. Do I do something wrong or is that some kind of new folder structure?

There are folders `conf` and `modules`

Also, there are no commands like `a2ensite`, `a2enmod` etc. in `/usr/sbin` and I can't find them anywhere. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large part of what a distribution like Ubuntu does is to integrate a large number of different software from a multitude of different origins and combine them into a coherent system. To do that, in many cases the original software has to be adapted or extended.

That's the case with Apache. The whole `*-available` and `*-enabled` structure is not the Apache projects doing, so to speak, but part of how Debian integrated the Apache HTTPd into its distribution. Therefore, you'll find it in Debian and Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu, but not in the "original" Apache that you compiled yourself.

But it's not that hard to build those structures yourself. You basically need to create the folders yourself, and have Apache read the configs in there with the `IncludeOptional` directive in `apache.conf`. That's basically what the Debian version of `apache.conf` does:

```
...
# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
...
# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/
...
```

The commands like `a2ensite`, `a2enmod` and so forth are also part of the Debian integration. In fact, most of those are symbolic links on `a2enmod`, which is a Perl script. All of them basically add (`a2en*`) or remove (`a2dis*`) the symbolic links from the respective `*-available` directory to the `*-enabled` directory. For example, `a2ensite mysite.conf` create a symlink in `site-enabled/mysite.conf` that refers to `site-available/mysite.conf`. And the `sites-enabled` directory can be integrated in `apache.conf`, as shown above.

So you can just create the symlinks yourself with `ln -s`, or you can write a little script in your language of choice to do that.

Comment: Is there an available Docker image with these options? I need the rewrite_module.c for my .htaccess to work in my framework.

Answer (score 2):

Those things are all Debian-specific; they are not present in the "original" Apache, only in the modified version shipped in Debian (and thus, in Ubuntu as well).

So, no, nothing is wrong with your installation, but many of the Debian-specific resources you can find will not apply to it.

By the way, I am not sure why you need Apache 2.4.23, but in any case it is available from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2). Those package should include `a2ensite` et al.

Comment: Oh, and is there a way to compile my own Debian-specific httpd? I didn't find any mirror.

Comment: I needed to compile it with specific CFLAGS, that's why I'm doing it manually.  Thank you for explanation

Comment: Well, you could download the Debian source packages, modify them to add your cflags, and recompile, but that requires some familiarity with Debian packaging.